# How can I show the latest added content to a specific link?

Tags: 8

I have content type `Videos`, lets say I have 5 videos, they have these url links:

- /videos/video-name-1
- /videos/video-name-2
- /videos/video-name-3
- /videos/video-name-4
- /videos/video-name-5

What I want is when I go to `/videos` I want this page to show the last video added (`/videos/video-name-5`) and I want to make this dynamic e.g. if I add a new video, when I visit `/videos` it will show me the page of that new video I added.

How can I achive this? As much as possible I don't want to use redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a views page that shows the most recent video.

- Structure > Views > **Add new view**

  - Title: "**Videos**"
  - Show content of type "**Video**" sorted by "**Newest first**"
  - Check "**Create a page**" option
  - Page title: "**Video**"
  - Path: "**videos**"
  - Display format: "**Unformatted list**" of "**Full posts**"
  - Items to display: "**1**"
  - Save & edit
  - Save again

Now go to the url: http://my-drupal-site.com/videos and it will display the most recent video via the view you created above